# How to set "todate picker" selected date as maximum date of "from datepicker" date

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar

I have two date picker `From and To`, here i can set `From datepicker` value as minimum date of `to datepicker`.

Now my requirement is ,if i select `To datepicker` date, i want to set it as maximum date of `From datepicker date`. I tried one solution, but its not working in my case.

```
private String fromDate;
private DatePickerDialog fromDatePicker;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener fromDatePickerListener;
private Calendar fromDateCalendar;
private String toDate;
private DatePickerDialog toDatePicker;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener toDatePickerListener;
private Calendar toDateCalendar;
```

Fromdatepicker OnDateSetListener method

```
 fromDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    fromDatePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        fromDate = fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
  (fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + 
   fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
         textviewFrom.setText(fromDate); 

toDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(fromDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis()); 
    } 

};
```

To datepicker OnDateSetListener method

```
 toDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 toDatePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        toDate = toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
 (toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + 
  toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        textviewTo.setText(toDate); 
todatepicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(-2208902400000L);
fromdatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(toDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

    } 

 }; 


toDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),toDatePickerListener, 
toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

fromDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),fromDatePickerListener, 
fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Textview listner for call datepicker dialog

```
textviewFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            fromDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
    textviewTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            toDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

I tried

```
fromDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(toDateCalendar.get‌​TimeInMillis());
```

in onDateSet method of toDatePickerListener, but its not 
   working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following way,Hope it may help you.

```
 private String selectedToDate = "";
 private String selectedFromDate = "";
 private Calendar calToDate, calFromDate;
```

Write this code in onCreate() method

```
calFromDate = convertToCalender(selectedFromDate);
calToDate = convertToCalender(selectedToDate);
```

Todate and FromDate TextView Clicks

```
textviewFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             showFromDatePicker(fromdateListener, calFromDate, calToDate);
        }
    });
textviewTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showToDatePicker(todateListener, calToDate, calFromDate);
        }
    });
```

toDate and fromDate Listener

```
 public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener fromdateListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                    calFromDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    selectedFromDate = returnFormattedDate(calFromDate.getTimeInMillis());
                    textviewFrom.setText(selectedFromDate);
                }
            };

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener todateListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                    calToDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    selectedToDate = returnFormattedDate(calToDate.getTimeInMillis());
                    textviewTo.setText(selectedToDate);
                }
};
private  String returnFormattedDate(long timeInMilliSec) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
                Locale.getDefault());
        return dateFormat.format(new Date(timeInMilliSec));
}
```

Methods to show DatePicker

```
private void showFromDatePicker(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener,
                                Calendar calendar,
                                Calendar minDateCalender) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                listener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        if (minDateCalender != null) {
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDateCalender.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        dialog.show();
    }

private void showToDatePicker(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener,
                                Calendar calendar,
                                Calendar maxDateCalender) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                listener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
       dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDateCalender.getTimeInMillis());

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Method to convert string date to Calender

```
private Calendar convertToCalender(String date) {
        Calendar mCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (date == null) {
            return mCalender;
        } else {
            try {
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date returnDate = formatter.parse(date);
                mCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
                mCalender.setTime(returnDate);
                return mCalender;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return mCalender;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hai its working fyn,thank u somuch,but only one problem still remaining..in showToDatePicker,i seted   dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(maxDateCalender.getTimeInMillis());,..like this always i want to show current day date as maximum in showToDatePicker,how can i achive dat one

Comment: To show current date as a maximum date in calender, You have to add **dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(Calender.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());** in showToDatePicker.

Comment: its working fyn.one more doubt,intital time when i open showToDatePicker,how to show showFromDatePicker  default date as minimum date in showToDatePicker  ?now i am getting showToDatePicker date as minimum date intial time i open

Comment: Add this one **dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calFromDate.get‌​TimeInMillis());**

Comment: intial time its not working,from second time onwords its working,still itial time  am gettin Todate value as minimum date..

Comment: when i open fragment intial time i set date from json response,so from and to date have values there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159871/discussion-between-user8737536-and-patel-dhara).

Answer (score 0):

If you are are using DatePicker widget in xml the following will work .

```
toDatePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            toDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            toDate = toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" +
                    (toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" +
                    toDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            fromdatePicker.setMaxDate(toDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
            //etToDate.setText(toDate);
        }

    };
```

Or if you opening DatePickerDialog oen after another . Then you should save the previously selected date and pass it to next DatePickerDialog before calling show.

```
pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxTime);// Set Max and min here
pickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: tried this,but its not working,pls check my updated code

Comment: Why are you setting Max and min time again in on click . This will reset the previous time . Remove these lines from both on click

Comment: if i select todate picker first time its working one time,otherwise no,in my case user can select from or to intially

Comment: Other wise how it will work ? You set setMaxDate inside the listener then it will work only after listener get called . You have to bind user to set toDate first or fromDate first which ever your need is.